# trying to find range of long data type in java

Tags: java

trying to verify range of long in java.. why is this program not working? it gives infinite loop (probably). i'm not getting output at the command line and the cursor keeps blinking.

```
class range
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
         long i;
     for(i=0;;i++)
    {
         long c= (long)(i+1);
         if(i>c)    //upper_limit+1=lower_limit
            break;  // hence, at i=upper_limit c(=i+1) < i

    }
    System.out.println("upper ="+i);
    for(i=-1;;i--)
    {
        long c=(long)(i-1);         
        if(i<c)             //lowerlimit-1=upperlimit
            break;          //hence at i=lowerlimit c(=i-1)>i
    }
    System.out.println("lower ="+i);
}
}
```

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE` is too mainstream for you?

Comment: You could use Long.MAX_VALUE and Long.MIN_VALUE?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program ?

Answer (score 7):

Your program will work *eventually* - but it's got to perform 2<sup>63</sup> iterations (in each direction) first. That's going to take a very long time. [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) and [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE) are rather simpler ways of finding this out. Or just look at [JLS 4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - ...
> - For `long`, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive

If you want to see your program finding the right values, just start it closer to the final result:

```
for(i=Long.MAX_VALUE - 10;;i++)
...
for(i=Long.MIN_VALUE + 10;;i--)
```

That quickly ends with output of:

```
upper =9223372036854775807
lower =-9223372036854775808
```

Comment: But `i > c` will never be `true`.. No?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it will overflow and become negative. Try `Long.MAX_VALUE + 1`, you'll see :)

Comment: thanks.. actually i'm only a begginer in JAVA and wasn't aware of the Long.MAX_VALUE/MIN_VALUE variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think your program is not correct? It simply will take a long while - until long overflows(about 2^63 iterations). I suggest that you use `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MIN_VALUE`  or if you want to avoid this solution use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for when overflow happens.

Also you may consider using the same program for `short` to verify it is correct, simply very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Long.MAX_VALUE and Long.MIN_VALUE

It will take lots of time to enumerate all 2^64 possible long values

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to start at 0 or -1.

If you want to verify MIN/Max values, try it like this:

```
class range
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
         long i;
     for(i=Long.MAX_VALUE;;i++)
    {
         long c= (long)(i+1);
         if(i>c)    //upper_limit+1=lower_limit
            break;  // hence, at i=upper_limit c(=i+1) < i

    }
    System.out.println("upper ="+i);
    for(i=Long.MIN_VALUE;;i--)
    {
        long c=(long)(i-1);         
        if(i<c)             //lowerlimit-1=upperlimit
            break;          //hence at i=lowerlimit c(=i-1)>i
    }
    System.out.println("lower ="+i);
}
}
```